# Chrome Developer tools numbers after each files name?

Tags: google-chrome, numbers, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

I was debugging my website using the developer tools, if you refer to my image, there are 2 styles.css overwrite one another.

It is weird though, because I remember I have only one style.css file attached but it is showing 2 style.css instead. I have checked the location but is exactly pointing to the same path with the same css file(but the content of the css is different.)

The only difference I can spot is the number after the css file name shown by the Devtools

```
style.css:839
style.css:190
```

What does it means actually?

Comment: It is the line number of the selector present in your file(style.css). In line number 190, you have added a style for the selector(providedSupport). In same file, you have added style for same selector at line number 839.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the line number of the selector present in your file(style.css). In line number 190, you have added a style for the selector(providedSupport). In same file, you have added style for same selector at line number 839

Have a look at Chrome dev tools, this has more feature : [Refer this link](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles)